# Hide `.DS_Store` when navigating the terminal with tab auto-complete

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

Typically when moving thru my terminal (Bash environment) I use tab to display my directory contents. `.DS_Store` is a lot of noise to see in *every* directory. I'm okay with the existence of `.DS_Store`, but I don't want it **ever** see it in my auto-tab-complete results.

An example is when you hit `<Tab>` after typing in `cd ~/dev/project-a/`

```
$ cd ~/dev/project-a/
 .DS_Store       .git/        Makefile
 .editorconfig   .gitignore   src/
```

Is there a clean solution to hiding `.DS_Store` from the results, without switching shell environments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ignore directory `.DS_Store` I suggest to add this to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
FIGNORE=DS_Store
```

Disadvantage: This ignores everything that ends with `.DS_Store`.